# Rails 4 rendering partials with assets extremely slow

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I recently upgraded our application to Rails 4. Since upgrading rendering times for a view with image assets loads extremely slowly.

A page with 10 assets can take as much as 8 seconds and some pages oh heroku will simply timeout due to the rendering taking too long.

I know in Rails 3.2.13 there was an issue with config.assets.debug set to true by default but that was fixed in Rails 4 I believe.

What could be causing such long rendering times?

Below is the production environment file for reference. Any other details required, please let me know.

```
Adventistmedia::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = true
  config.eager_load = true
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.cache_store = :dalli_store, {compress: true}
  config.serve_static_assets = true # fixes heroku issue
  config.static_cache_control = "public, max-age=30758400"
  config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
  config.assets.compile = false
  config.assets.digest = true
  config.assets.cache_store = :dalli_store
  config.assets.debug = false
  config.after_initialize do
    Delayed::Job.scaler = :heroku_cedar
  end
  config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif fontawesome-webfont.ttf fontawesome-webfont.eot FontAwesome.otf fontawesome-webfont.woff)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new
  config.action_controller.asset_host = "//#{ENV['FOG_DIRECTORY']}.s3.amazonaws.com"
end
```

Comment: Hi, do you see the following lines when deploying your rails application?
-----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline  
       Running: rake assets:precompile
Also if a public/assets/manifest.yml is detected in your app, Heroku will assume you are handling asset compilation yourself and will not attempt to compile your assets

Comment: Yes i see "Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline Running: rake assets:precompile"
There isno manifest.yml in the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was with carrierwave and the method for calling the thumbnail URLs. I've created a ticket for the issue https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/issues/1218

It looks like the issue comes from the method used for calling a thumbnail url of the image.

These are the time differences to load a partial with 8 thumbnail urls on our staging server: 
image_tag(asset.media.url(:thumb).to_s) = 9.4 seconds average
image_tag(asset.media.thumb.url.to_s) = 40ms average

That's 23x slower!

If i was to simply call asset.media.url.to_s the time would be back to normal but adding the thumbnail size option seems to cause large performance issues.